# Modeling Horsepower as a function of engine speed and throttle position in an ICE

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

I'm a grass roots motorsports guy who is into road racing.  I'm doing some precision tuning on the horsepower levels on my car to meet specifics of our rule sets.

I have lots of logged data of different ECU tune profiles that gives me engine speed and throttle position as independent input variables with engine horsepower (read from a chassis dynamometer) as the dependent or output variable.

Is there a simplistic way for me to build a model in Excel that I could feed several data sets to to then allow me to predict engine horsepower as a function of those two input variables?  Thank you!

Comment: But what about the effect of things like a tuned exhaust?

Comment: So you have several sets of 3d data, rpm vs throttle angle vs hp. One common way of obtaining an average is to interpolate them to a uniform grid of rpm and throttle angle, and then average those values at each grid point. You can use Excel to do this but it is rather an involved exercise, or you can use an extension such as http://www.xlxtrfun.com/ which does the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: If you already have measured data, that can be much more valuable and accurate than a mathematical model someone comes up with off the top of their head. Curve fitting and interpolation is the simplest way to use it, but you can also make a detailed engine model by using the math behind each component and interface, and twerking various coefficients until it fits your data.  I would suggest python with pandas and matplotlib packages if you are up for some coding.